# SSRS Report giving error for Join expression

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have declared a multi value parameter in my SSRS report. The parameter is a Date and it has multiple values like:

```
06/01/2021
05/01/2021
04/01/2021
```

Now when I select date as `06/01/2021, 05/01/2021` then the expression should show as `Reportname_` with previous months first and last dates.
Example: if I select date as

```
06/01/2021
05/01/2021
04/01/2021
```

then result should be

> Reportname_05/01/2021-05/31/2021_04/01/2021-04/30/2021_03/01/2021-03/31/2021

I tried with Join but getting error. The expression I am using is

```
Join(dateadd(“m”,-1,dateserial(year(Parameters!date.Value(0)), month(Parameters!date.Value(0)), 1)) & 
"-" & 
dateadd(“m”,0,dateserial(year(Parameters!date.Value(0)), month(Parameters!date.Value(0)), 0)), "_")
```

Comment: Please provide more details about the expression that returns the error

Comment: @niktrs The Value expression for the textrun ‘textbox1.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30518] Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Join' can be called with these arguments:
    'Public Function Join(SourceArray() As String, [Delimiter As String = " "]) As String': Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of String'.
    'Public Function Join(SourceArray() As Object, [Delimiter As String = " "]) As String': Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of Object'.

Comment: Join(dateadd(“m”,-1,dateserial(year(Parameters!date.Value(0)),month(Parameters!date.Value(0)),1))&"-"&dateadd(“m”,0,dateserial(year(Parameters!date.Value(0)),month(Parameters!date.Value(0)),0)),"_")

Answer (score 1):

You have to use custom code to parse your parameter and create the string expression

Add the following custom code to your report

```
Public Function ParseDate(ByVal parameter as Parameter) as String

Dim s as String 
Dim seperator as String 
Dim dt as Date

    For i as integer = 0 to parameter.Count-1
     dt = DateSerial(Year(parameter.Value(i)), Month(parameter.Value(i)), 1)
      s = s + seperator + Format(DateAdd("m",-1,dt),"MM/dd/yyyy") + "-" + Format(DateAdd("d",-1, dt),"MM/dd/yyyy") 
      seperator = "_"

    Next
 
   Return s
End Function
```

For your textbox returning the report name and date values use the following expression

```
=Globals!ReportName & "_" & Code.ParseDate(Parameters!Date)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, If the select date is 06/20/2021 then also the parsed expression date should be 05/01/2021-05/31/2021. Then what we need to change in above function?

Comment: It needs to use DateSerial to get the first day of month. The rest of the calculations may remain the same. I have updated my answer to reflect the change